# When using software to infect others, how are hackers them selves not infected?

Tags: virus

I assume all hacking software (password cracker, R.A.T. etc...) are infected. So the hackers using it are probably hacked too, right ?

Comment: Why do you assume hacking tools contain Trojans? That doesn't seem like a very well-thought-out business plan (if you attack your customers, you will soon have nome).

Comment: Because hacking tools are most of the time proposed by hacking sites, so hackers. And their objective is to hack. So it's an easy way to do it. They say "don't worry, your anti virus will warn you but it's normal, just ignore it". And then, people get infected.

Answer (score 5):

Hackers won't really care about the tools being infected or not. They usually uses an environment that is not theirs anyway. Good hackers are also able to program the hacking tool by themselves, so they know it's not rigged.

Since you mentioned the [virus](/questions/tagged/virus) tag, I'll also develop on virus creation. You can do this using sandboxes (virtual machines) so that your computer won't be infected by the virus.

Comment: I meant: when hackers download on the internet any hacking software, it is surely already infected by a virus/Trojan. Because it's an easy way to hack someone else. You propose a hacking software to download which is, in fact, hacked itself to get control of your computer. So that's why I'm wondering if in fact, they aren't hacked themselves without knowing it. What do you mean by "uses an environment that is not theirs anyway" ? Sandboxes ? I'm not familiar with that, could you tell a me a little more about it please ?

Comment: They use your computer already :) well I'm exaggerating here, but they usually have control of other computers already. They use them as "base".

Comment: But to have control of other computers, they have to have R.A.T.; so first they need to download it. And possibly get infected.

Comment: @Steve some hacks are easy and do not require complicated tools.

Answer (score 3):

You are currently assuming hacking software and scripts are some kind of malware?

Firstly this question appears quite unsupported as you have not provided much context.

Secondly, no. if you are talking about malware than yes a hacker could infect them selves if they messed up but if they created the virus they would have found a ground-zero to distribute from, why would someone distribute from their own machine? it would have also most likely been created in a virtual machine.

In regards to software like, metasploit? these are attacks not infections. you have a target not free roaming code leaking into the world.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that hacking software contain R.A.T. because it's an easy way to hack others. Let's say you propose a password cracker to download on a hacking site; but in fact, you hide a RAT in it so when the person will open it, he will first ignore the antivirus warning (because most of hacking tools are detected as risky) and then get infected.

Comment: in a situation like that, use only open source when possible. check hashes. compile the code your self.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your answer.